# Bring UITextField Keyboard to Front

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield

I created a custom `UIAlertView` (from scratch, not subclassed in any way) class that works very well, but I'm having an issue when the alert has a text field. In this particular instance, when I tap the email address field the keyboard appears under my popup alert. The view that this popup is called from also has a `UITextField` (a comment box). I've noticed I only have this problem if I tap the popup text field (email address) AFTER taping the main view text field (comment box). The text fields are NOT using the same delegate.

[image]

Is there a way to force the keyboard to the front of the view hierarchy?

UPDATE:
Code to add text field to popup (this is one in my alert class `PopupDialog.m`)

```
self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 34)];
_textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:18];
_textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
_textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
_textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor white];
_textField.delegate = self;
_textField.placeholder = @"email@domain.com";
```

It is later added to the popup view above the buttons. The semi-transparent black background and popup view are finally added to the view hierarchy by:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] addSubview:background];
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] addSubview:self];
```

Comment: It would help if you could show the code that creates the alertview. For example do you use alertViewStyle to have it display the textfield?

Comment: I've added the code that adds the textfield to the view. I think there is something getting confused with the 2 UITextField delegates. The rights ones are being called, but the keyboard isn't being brought to the front.

Comment: How are you adding the custom alert to the view hierarchy?

Comment: okay this is going to sound very hacky, but what you could do is, subclass your UITextField and put in the method -(UIView*)inputView{} what that is, is the method that is called when the keyboard is about to appear, intercept the keyboard UIView* keyboard = [super inputView]; and then pass then add that view to the window.

Comment: as long as the textfield of your alert is firstresponder, when you tap the keyboard it should work

Comment: I've added the code showing how the popup is added to the view hierarchy.

Comment: @A'saDickens that doesn't work because [super inputView] returns nil by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the same keyboard that was presented for the 'comments' `UITextField` (beneath the popup) was being used for the 'email' `UITextField` in the popup. I had to move the popup and semi-transparent black background behind this keyboard view.

```
int count = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count];
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:count - 2] addSubview:background];
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:count - 2] addSubview:self];
```

where the view at `count - 1` is the keyboard view.